# union all with not exists and insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query in which i should verify if the records are already there, if they are, don't insert the data again.

I am writing this as an example, I don't know the correct syntax for what i'm trying to achieve. Please find my try below.

```
select * from
(
insert into dbo.myTable
select mt.* from #myTemp mt
union all
select * from #someTemp1
union all
select * from #someTemp2
) tb
where not exists ( select tb.* )
```

Is this the right way to use insert into with `union all` if `not exists`?
I found some examples with select `union all` `where not exists` but I would like to see one with `insert` as well.

I am also curios if it's possible to do this without using **merge** .

Comment: Take a look at [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), it will help you avoid all of the problems you're currently facing.

Comment: Is there any way in which I could improve the question (regarding the downvote). I want for the quality of my questions to be better. Any remark is well received

Comment: "Is this the right way..." is opinion-based and off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Does your query work, or are you getting an error?   If it works, then why the question?

Comment: oh, thank you. You are right. Well, it doesn't work because I don't know the correct syntax. I wanted to say: "I don't know how to write the syntax for what i want, but should be something like this. If not, please maybe tell me how I should write it.". Will edit my question

Comment: A good search term you might want to try is "upsert". There are a lot of ways to solve this, but Merge is the standard MSSQL solution.

Comment: @JonWilson thank for the suggestion. A search with upsert gave me a lot of good examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` as suggested in comments or just `substract` from sum existing values.

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable(col INT);

CREATE TABLE #myTemp(col INT);
CREATE TABLE #someTemp1(col INT);
CREATE TABLE #someTemp2(col INT);

INSERT INTO #myTable(col) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO #myTemp(col) VALUES (10), (20), (30);
INSERT INTO #someTemp1(col) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO #someTemp2(col) VALUES (11), (2), (31);

INSERT INTO #myTable(col)
(
  SELECT mt.col FROM #myTemp mt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col FROM #someTemp1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col FROM #someTemp2
)
EXCEPT
SELECT col FROM #myTable;


SELECT *
FROM #myTable;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/377467)**</kbd>

Comment: I have multiple columns. How can your query be adapted for mutiple columns, am I getting it right?: `INSERT INTO #myTable(col1, col2, col3)
(
  SELECT mt.col1, mt.col2, mt.col3 FROM #myTemp mt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM #someTemp1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM #someTemp2
)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #myTable;`

Comment: @CM2K exactly just use multiple columns `EXCEPT SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM #myTable`